# Make D3 multi line chart in X1-Y1-X2-Y2 and X1-Y1-Y2-Y3 format

Tags: d3.js

I want to make two types of graph from the data array by using d3. The first graph should be having 2 x-axis values and 2 y-axis values i.e. X1-Y1-X2-Y2, so there will be 2 lines in the chart. In the second type, the data is having 1 x-axis value and other 3 are y-axis values, so the data will be having 3 lines in the chart. The data array example might be like this,

```html
//data for X1-Y1-X2-Y2 format
var data1 = [
{x1:10, y1:43, x2:15, y2:55},
{x1:20, y1:33, x2:22, y2:21},
{x1:30, y1:56, x2:27, y2:29},
]

//data for X1-Y1-Y2-Y3 format
var data2 = [
{x1:10, y1:43, y2:15, y3:55},
{x1:20, y1:33, y2:22, y3:21},
{x1:30, y1:56, y2:27, y3:29},
]
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything, what error do you get?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you stuck?